# Build sbt project as a part of Maven project

Tags: java, scala, maven, build, sbt

I have a Java Maven project that depends on a Scala sbt project. 
Is it possible to make that project into a dependency of Maven project? Java uses classes and objects from Scala Sbt project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to publish to your maven local repository (~/.m2)

`sbt publishM2`

and set in maven pom dependencies to your sbt project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${organization from sbt artifact}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${name from sbt artifact}</artifactId>
    <version>${version from sbt artifact}</version>
</dependency>
```